# wifi won't stay connected

Tags: networking, wireless, drivers, broadcom

I have a HP Pavillion dv6000 with Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and a Broadcom wireless card (BCM4312).

My Ethernet connection is fine. But when the wifi is turned on, it will stay connected for a short time and then disconnect and reconnect again. The wireless card is supposed to use the b43 driver, but it still does not hold the connection.

How can I fix my WiFi problem?

The output from the diagnostic script: http://paste.ubuntu.com/10988134/

Comment: Please run the script that is in the accepted answer in the link below so we may see the information needed to help diagnose the issue.
<http://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-
what-can-i-do>

Comment: My wifi works but does not hold connection, here is the script.

Comment: Where is the output from the script?

Comment: i ran a script that gave me a wireless-info.txt file but its too long to post. Which output am i looking for ? I am very new to all of this but I'm willing to try anything

Comment: You could copy the contents of the wireless-info file and paste it at paste.ubuntu.com and post the URL

Comment: paste.ubuntu.com link is in the directions at the link you ran the script from.

Comment: Here is the URL that you asked for http://paste.ubuntu.com/10988134/  and i hope i have given enough info for someone can help me. Thank you, Ted Tarant

Comment: And a special thank you to Wild Man and Jeremy31 for trying your best to help me !!!

Comment: Sorry it took me so long to see you posted the information, for some reason I am not receiving notifications about comments.

Comment: If it does not work properly after reinstalling the b43 driver then post a new script file so we can see what is going on using the b43 driver. Thanks

Comment: Here is the new URL Script after running your help commands: http://paste.ubuntu.com/11171404/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please do:

```
sudo apt-get purge bcmwl-kernel-source
```

the above command will remove the wl driver that is the wrong driver for your device.
The next command installs the b43 driver that your device needs.

```
sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-installer
```

Reboot

Go into network manager and remove wireless connections then reboot and set the settings to match the screenshots.[image: DNS SETTINGS][image: IPV6 SETTINGS]

Also reboot your router.

Comment: Well... I appreciate all the help. I ran the above script and and did the reboot and the same thing keeps happening. I have no idea what to do after doing this several times. I am at this computer all the time and apologize for my delay in also returning my results. I don't get it???

Comment: http://paste.ubuntu.com/11171404/        This is the new URL

Comment: I added more directions to the answer.

Comment: Dear Wild Man, Thank you so much for the last set of instructions. It is now holding the connection, however when I changed the METHOD to: DHCP address's only, I could not connect to the internet. So I changed it to DHCP and I am now on the web holding the wifi connection. You have stuck with me to get here(fixed) and it is so well appreciate, and most of all I learned alot about my computer, Ubuntu and the GREAT support. I look forward to helping someone else. Now I hope people that use the Broadcom b43 driver can use this vital information. THANKS WILD MAN !!!      ted